# Bernoulli's lemniscate inside rectangle

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Determine the vertices of the rectangle with the smallest field with sides parallel to the axis of $OXY$, which contains the Bernoulli's lemniscate $(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)=0$ inside.

I would be grateful for your hints.

Comment: "Smallest field" - does that mean smallest area?

Comment: I think the question makes sense as is. The Bernoulli lemniskat is a bounder curve. Among all rectangles with sides parallel to the axes that contain it, there is a smallest one with respect to inclusion. 
Hint: You need to find the points where the tangent lines are parallel to the axes.

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of computing the maximum and minimum? In both the $x$- and $y$-direction There are a few ways to do this, but it depends on what you're familiar with. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: My idea is naive - find min of $f(x,y)=4xy$ with condition $(x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)=0$ using Lagrange multipliers.